# Decomposition of standard deviation into components

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, variance, standard-deviation

I am currently trying to figure out whether it is possible to "decompose" a standard deviation. I'd like to illustrate my question with an example: Say you have 10 countries, and you compute the standard deviation of labor productivity. Each country has 3 sectors which it uses to produce, namely agriculture, manufacturing, and services. You can compute total economy productivity then as a weighted sum of the sector labour productivities, where the weight used is a sector's employment share (shares of agriculture, manufacturing, and services logically add up to 1). My question is then the following. Is there a way to compute the standard deviation of these three sectors, such that they "aggregate" to the standard deviation of the economy-wide labour productivity?

What I am trying to do is compare labour productivity dispersion for the different sectors, and their role in accounting for total dispersion of labour productivity, hence why I am interested in finding out whether a standard deviation can be decomposed (into sectoral components in this case).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best,

Oz

Comment: If mutually independent random variables $X_i$ have respective variances $\sigma_i^2.$ then $Var(\sum_I X_i) =$ $\sum_i \sigma_i^2.$ So you could start with variances, add, and take square roots to get appropriate SD's.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by your first "the standard deviation of labor productivity".  Is that the standard deviation based on the overall productivities of individual countries compared to the combined mean productivity of the countries together?  In that case I doubt the variation within countries is directly relevant.

Comment: Hi Bruce, Thanks for your answer! I will try that.

Comment: Henry, yes the first "standard deviation" is based on total economy (so indeed overall) productivities of individual countries compared to the mean productivity of the countries together (so the cross-country average). In the case of the standard deviations for the sectors, I am still computing the standard deviation based on the productivities of individual countries compared to the combined mean productivity of the countries together, but here the productivity value I use is the sector-level one, not the overall (total economy) productivity. In this case, can the first std dev be decomposed?